# Let $M$ be a semisimple $R$-module and $S=\text{End}_{R}(M)$. Prove that $M$ is a semisimple $S$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a semisimple $R$-module and $S=\text{End}_{R}(M)$. Prove that $M$ is a semisimple $S$-module.

Here $M$ is a module over an aribtrary ring $R$.

My attempt is like this.

We know that if $M=A$ $\oplus$ $B$ as $R$-modules, then the sequence $0$ $\rightarrow$ $A$ $\rightarrow$ $M$ splits, with $i_{A}$ : $A$ $\rightarrow$ $M$ the inclusion map.

Also, $M$ is semisimple, then for any submodule $A$, we have $A$ is a direct summand, so the previous sequence splits.

Now, let $N$ $\leq$ $M$ as $S$-modules and we consider $0$ $\rightarrow$ $N$ $\rightarrow$ $M$ and want to see that sequence splits, because if it splits, then $N$ is a direct summand of $M$ and $M$ then it is a semisimple $S$-module.

Any suggestion on how to see that $0$ $\rightarrow$ $N$ $\rightarrow$ $M$ splits, or maybe other way to prove $M$ is a semisimple $S$-module